# CSS/JS issue on the menu in my prestashop site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prestashop

I have some css issues on my prestashop site on the top menu block. 
The icon of the cloud that appears on "Novedades" menu item is not set correctly must be a little higher.

Here is my css code:

```
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-contener {
clear: both;
}
.sf-right {
  margin-right: 14px;
  float: right;
  width: 7px;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu {
margin: 10px 0;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:980px;/* 980 */
background: #383838;
/*  @media (max-width: 450px) {
    .sf-menu {
      display: none; }    */
}
.sf-menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: -999em;
width: 10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
width: 100%;
}

.sf-menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

.sf-menu li:hover {
visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
/*border-right: 1px solid #777;*/
}
.sf-menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
color:#fff;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
/*padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
top: 35px; /* match top ul list item height */
z-index: 99;
width:auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.cat-title {
display: none;
}
.sf-menu {
float: left;
margin-bottom: -2em;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background: url('http://www.xxxx.com/themes/xxxxxx/img/cabecera.png') repeat left center; 

}
.sf-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display:block;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
    line-height:35px;   
    border: 10;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Handlee;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
color: #916e6e;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.sf-menu li ul {
  border:1px solid #f1b6b1; box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  width:500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
  top:0;
  background: white;
}
.sf-menu li li {
background: white; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height:35px; 
  line-height:35px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.sf-menu li li a {
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: capitalize;
top:0;  
}
/*
ul.sf-menu li a {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
*/
.sf-menu li li li {
background: white;
width:140px;
}
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: white;
   background: url('http://www.xxxx.com/themes/xxxxx/img/boton-b.png') no-repeat center 0px; 
}
.sf-menu ul li:hover, .sf-menu ul li.sfHover,
.sf-menu ul li a:focus, .sf-menu ul li a:hover, .sf-menu ul li a:active {
background: #eecfd0; //#4e4e4e; 
outline: 0;
} 
/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
padding-right:  2.25em;
min-width: 1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
padding-top: 20px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
position: absolute;
display: block;
right: 10px;
top: 1.05em; /* IE6 only */
width: 10px;
height: 35px;
text-indent:  -999em;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('../img/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
top: 11px;
background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul {
background: url('../img/shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
}
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
background: transparent;
}
li.sf-search {
  background: inherit;
  float: right;
  line-height: 25px;
  background:transparent;
}
li.sf-search input {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 18px 6px 0 0;
  background: #fff url('../../../../img/search-zoom3.png') no-repeat left center;
  border:1px solid #777;
}


/* hack IE7 */
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited {height:34px !IE;}
.sf-menu li li {
width:200px;
background:#726f72 !IE;
}

#block_top_menu .category-thumbnail {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none; }
  #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%; }
    #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div img {
      max-width: 100%; }
#block_top_menu li.category-thumbnail {
  padding-right: 0; }




/* Mobile Item */
.sf-menu-phone-item { display:none; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:none; position:absolute; top:7px; right:0; background:url('http://www.xxxxx.com/themes/xxxx/img/icon-mobile-nav.png') top right no-repeat #29addd; width:50px; height:50px; text-indent:-9999px; border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger:hover { background-color:#333; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger.active { background-position:bottom right; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:13px;}
}
/* Tablet Only Queries */
@media only screen and (min-width: 531px) and (max-width: 786px)  { 
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:12px;}
}

/* Phone Only Queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 530px) { 
    .sf-menu a{
        top:5px;
    }
    #sf-menu-header {height:auto; }
    #sf-menu-top-nav {margin-left:-2%; margin-right:-2%;}
    /*.sf-menu {display:none; } */
    .sf-menu {width:100%; height:auto; margin:10px 0 0 0; position:static !important}
    .sf-menu li {width:100%; background:#f4f4f4;  border-top:1px solid #fff !important; border-bottom:1px solid #999 !important; -webkit-border-radius:0; border-radius:0; }
    .sf-menu li:hover {background:#de8686;}
    .sf-menu li ul {width:100%; position:static !important; background:#ccc;}
    .sf-menu li li {width:100% !important; background:#ccc; }
    /*.sf-menu li li li {display:none !important;}*/
    .sf-menu-phone-item { display:block; }
    #sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:block; }
    .sf-search {padding:10px;} 
    #searchbox {margin-left:15px;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"] {width:80%;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"]:focus, #searchbox input[type="text"]:hover {width:80%;}
    #searchbox .button {width:10%;}
    #header_logo { padding-right:50px; text-align:left !important;}
}
```

I have tried applying the a class the same style I have for the a.sf-with-ul class

```
ul.sf-menu li a {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Which in fact does work, but then the hover pink selected height of the subcategories in "washitape" category are too much (which is even worst).

EDIT: (js file that generates the menu)

```
/*
 * jQuery Superfish Menu Plugin - v1.7.4
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var methods = (function () {
        // private properties and methods go here
        var c = {
                bcClass: 'sf-breadcrumb',
                menuClass: 'sf-js-enabled',
                anchorClass: 'sf-with-ul',
                menuArrowClass: 'sf-arrows'
            },
            ios = (function () {
                var ios = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
                if (ios) {
                    // iOS clicks only bubble as far as body children
                    $(window).load(function () {
                        $('body').children().on('click', $.noop);
                    });
                }
                return ios;
            })(),
            wp7 = (function () {
                var style = document.documentElement.style;
                return ('behavior' in style && 'fill' in style && /iemobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
            })(),
            toggleMenuClasses = function ($menu, o) {
                var classes = c.menuClass;
                if (o.cssArrows) {
                    classes += ' ' + c.menuArrowClass;
                }
                $menu.toggleClass(classes);
            },
            setPathToCurrent = function ($menu, o) {
                return $menu.find('li.' + o.pathClass).slice(0, o.pathLevels)
                    .addClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass)
                        .filter(function () {
                            return ($(this).children(o.popUpSelector).hide().show().length);
                        }).removeClass(o.pathClass);
            },
            toggleAnchorClass = function ($li) {
                $li.children('a').toggleClass(c.anchorClass);
            },
            toggleTouchAction = function ($menu) {
                var touchAction = $menu.css('ms-touch-action');
                touchAction = (touchAction === 'pan-y') ? 'auto' : 'pan-y';
                $menu.css('ms-touch-action', touchAction);
            },
            applyHandlers = function ($menu, o) {
                var targets = 'li:has(' + o.popUpSelector + ')';
                if ($.fn.hoverIntent && !o.disableHI) {
                    $menu.hoverIntent(over, out, targets);
                }
                else {
                    $menu
                        .on('mouseenter.superfish', targets, over)
                        .on('mouseleave.superfish', targets, out);
                }
                var touchevent = 'MSPointerDown.superfish';
                if (!ios) {
                    touchevent += ' touchend.superfish';
                }
                if (wp7) {
                    touchevent += ' mousedown.superfish';
                }
                $menu
                    .on('focusin.superfish', 'li', over)
                    .on('focusout.superfish', 'li', out)
                    .on(touchevent, 'a', o, touchHandler);
            },
            touchHandler = function (e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $ul = $this.siblings(e.data.popUpSelector);

                if ($ul.length > 0 && $ul.is(':hidden')) {
                    $this.one('click.superfish', false);
                    if (e.type === 'MSPointerDown') {
                        $this.trigger('focus');
                    } else {
                        $.proxy(over, $this.parent('li'))();
                    }
                }
            },
            over = function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                $this.siblings().superfish('hide').end().superfish('show');
            },
            out = function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                if (ios) {
                    $.proxy(close, $this, o)();
                }
                else {
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    o.sfTimer = setTimeout($.proxy(close, $this, o), o.delay);
                }
            },
            close = function (o) {
                o.retainPath = ($.inArray(this[0], o.$path) > -1);
                this.superfish('hide');

                if (!this.parents('.' + o.hoverClass).length) {
                    o.onIdle.call(getMenu(this));
                    if (o.$path.length) {
                        $.proxy(over, o.$path)();
                    }
                }
            },
            getMenu = function ($el) {
                return $el.closest('.' + c.menuClass);
            },
            getOptions = function ($el) {
                return getMenu($el).data('sf-options');
            };

        return {
            // public methods
            hide: function (instant) {
                if (this.length) {
                    var $this = this,
                        o = getOptions($this);
                    if (!o) {
                        return this;
                    }
                    var not = (o.retainPath === true) ? o.$path : '',
                        $ul = $this.find('li.' + o.hoverClass).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass).children(o.popUpSelector),
                        speed = o.speedOut;

                    if (instant) {
                        $ul.show();
                        speed = 0;
                    }
                    o.retainPath = false;
                    o.onBeforeHide.call($ul);
                    $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animationOut, speed, function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        o.onHide.call($this);
                    });
                }
                return this;
            },
            show: function () {
                var o = getOptions(this);
                if (!o) {
                    return this;
                }
                var $this = this.addClass(o.hoverClass),
                    $ul = $this.children(o.popUpSelector);

                o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);
                $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animation, o.speed, function () {
                    o.onShow.call($ul);
                });
                return this;
            },
            destroy: function () {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        o = $this.data('sf-options'),
                        $hasPopUp;
                    if (!o) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    // remove event handlers
                    $this.off('.superfish').off('.hoverIntent');
                    // clear animation's inline display style
                    $hasPopUp.children(o.popUpSelector).attr('style', function (i, style) {
                        return style.replace(/display[^;]+;?/g, '');
                    });
                    // reset 'current' path classes
                    o.$path.removeClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass).addClass(o.pathClass);
                    $this.find('.' + o.hoverClass).removeClass(o.hoverClass);
                    o.onDestroy.call($this);
                    $this.removeData('sf-options');
                });
            },
            init: function (op) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.data('sf-options')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.superfish.defaults, op),
                        $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    o.$path = setPathToCurrent($this, o);

                    $this.data('sf-options', o);

                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    applyHandlers($this, o);

                    $hasPopUp.not('.' + c.bcClass).superfish('hide', true);

                    o.onInit.call(this);
                });
            }
        };
    })();

    $.fn.superfish = function (method, args) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else {
            return $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.fn.superfish');
        }
    };

    $.fn.superfish.defaults = {
        popUpSelector: 'ul,.sf-mega', // within menu context
        hoverClass: 'sfHover',
        pathClass: 'overrideThisToUse',
        pathLevels: 1,
        delay: 800,
        animation: {opacity: 'show'},
        animationOut: {opacity: 'hide'},
        speed: 'normal',
        speedOut: 'fast',
        cssArrows: true,
        disableHI: false,
        onInit: $.noop,
        onBeforeShow: $.noop,
        onShow: $.noop,
        onBeforeHide: $.noop,
        onHide: $.noop,
        onIdle: $.noop,
        onDestroy: $.noop
    };

    // soon to be deprecated
    $.fn.extend({
        hideSuperfishUl: methods.hide,
        showSuperfishUl: methods.show
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think u missed the class name

```
class="sf-with-ul"
```

in the anchor tag

Comment: how to add it on the prestashop system? the menu is autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding your css as below:

```
  .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    color: #916e6e;
    white-space:nowrap;
     padding-right: 2.25em;
      min-width: 1px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      margin-top: -20px;
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
add `class="sf-with-ul"` like below to category Novedades

```
<a href="/novedades" title="Novedades" class="sf-with-ul">Novedades</a>
```

and remove `class="sf-with-ul"` from all subcategories' `<a>` tag of Washi Tape
like

```
<a href="http://www.dulcewashitape.com/por-colores/" title="Por colores">Por colores</a>
```

Comment: @ user2348511: try EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: Hi, I know the solution is to add that class but I do not know how, as the menu is autogenerated by prestashop on a js file. I attach the js on my original post

Comment: yaah, then its not a CSS issue its JS issue. please Change your title of question and add javascript and jquery tags to your question. that will help you more.

Comment: `   toggleAnchorClass = function ($li) {
           //     $li.children('a').toggleClass(c.anchorClass);
            },`  try by commenting this line in your js file. Not sure this will work or not if not make as original. check the changes. you need to check by this. which line of JS is adding `anchorClass` to subcategory. you need to remove that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77170/discussion-between-kiran-and-user2348511).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this attribute class="sf-with-ul"

change it like below.

```
<a href="" title="Novedades" class="sf-with-ul">Novedades</a>
```

Comment: how to add it on the prestashop system? the menu is autogenerated.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know anything about prestashop.